# Rails adds DB column name to error message

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to show different message than predefined one. And in my model file i added this line to check if that company exists in db.
I am using Rails 5.2.2

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    validates :tax_no, :uniqueness => {message: "This tax number has already been used"}
end
```

And i got the result as :

> Company tax no This tax number has already been used

How can i remove that "Company tax no" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends how you display your error message.

You will get proper idea from below,

```
u = User.new

u.valid?
# => false

u.errors.messages
# {:email=>["This field is required.", "This field is required.", "This field is required."], :password=>["This field is required."]}

u.errors.full_messages
# => ["Email This field is required.", "Password This field is required."]

u.errors.messages[:email]
# => "This field is required."
```

You have to inspect your view part and use `@company.errors.messages[:tax_no]` if `@company.valid?` is false for `tax_no`